# How to add checkbox in html table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need to add a checkbox in a html table I know the usual method like

```
    <td>  
        <input type="checkbox" name ="chk1" />  
    </td>
```

My current code is

```
string html=""; 
html += "<table>";
html += "<tr><th>" + "A" + "</th><th>" + "B" + "</th><th>" + "C" + </th></tr>";
html += "<tr><td>" + "0" + "</td><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + "2" + </td></td>+"<input type="checkbox" name ="chk1" /> "  +</td>  </tr>"; 
html += "</table>";
```

but this gives an error

Comment: Change the double Quotes " to Single ' for type and name values... it will work

Comment: I like SO's syntax highlighting, it clearly points out to you: where the error is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed some quotes

please use this code

```
string html=""; 
html += "<table>";
html += "<tr><th>" + "A" + "</th><th>" + "B" + "</th><th>" + "C" + "</th></tr>";
html += "<tr><td>" + "0" + "</td><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + "2" + "</td></td>"+"<input type='checkbox' name ='chk1' /> "  +"</td>  </tr>"; 
html += "</table>";
```

Comment: hey dude, we are not asp.net developers, just copied his code and edited :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're missing a quote, also you can get rid of some of the quotes (and rows):

```
string html=""; 
html += "<table>";
html += "<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>";
html += "<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></td><input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"chk1\" /></td></tr>"; 
html += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of concatenations, just put single quotes outside as given in the example below:

```
string html = ''; 
html += '<table>';
html += '<tr><th>A</th><th>A</th><th>C</th></tr>';
html += '<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></td><input type="checkbox" name ="chk1"  /></td></tr>'; 
html += '</table>';
```

Comment: @krshekhar: We all just copied the OP's code and helping him out to close the quotes properly. The error you mentioned is an html structure error not a code error.

Comment: @krshekhar: If you are agree then undo all the down votes you did. Thanks.

Comment: but I am not able to up-vote  because it(SO) is not letting me to do so unless you edit your answer.

Comment: I don't say to give up vote, but you have an option of undo just move your mouse on down arrow (then you will see an option of undo in a tool tip) and click it again.

Comment: Even I am unable to do so. It is giving me the same message.

Comment: :) There, I gave you a +1 :) kreshekhar is having a bad day :)